# XCUITest - Cell Selected not showing in hierarchy tree in iOS 15

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, xcuitest, ios15

We recently upgraded to XCode 13 / iOS 15 and cells are not longer showing "Selected" in the element hierarchy tree, using po XCUIApplication().

This is what we saw prior to the upgrade:

[image]

[image]

Using 14.4 or prior shows "Selected" but using a simulator with iOS 15 does not.

Does anyone have a solution or workaround for this?

Cell:
[image]

Comment: And what are you seeing now? Please provide full debug output.

Comment: It's not showing "Selected". So it's the same tree but not with the "Selected" that is highlighted in red.

Comment: I’m curious about what else exists in the cell. Perhaps something we can get a state from? Do you have access to the application code?

Comment: Querying for isSelected also seems to not work on iOS15 where it worked on iOS14…

Comment: Yeah isSelected isn't working because its not marking the element as Selected in the hierarchy tree.  Thats actually how I figured out this issue because our tests that use isSelected were failing.

Comment: @MikeCollins I do have access to the code.  There is just text in the cell.  I added a screenshot showing the layout of the cell to the question/post.

Comment: Does the radio button have any attribute hinting at its state? I have a similar UI I work with - my checkboxes are images so I change their name based on state. I can then determine my cell is selected based it containing an image with a specific "selected" string in its name.

Comment: Since you have access to the code you could add the state of the button to its AccessiblityIdentifier. That usually shows up in the tree and would allow you to check it during testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I ran the simulator using Rosetta, this is working now.

Within Applications, right click on XCode and show package contents.  Contents > Developer > Applications > Simulator.  Right click and select Get Info.  Check Open Using Rosetta.